# MiniProfiler - ProfiledDbDataAdapter

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

Trying to get MiniProfiler to profile loading a DataTable via a Stored Proc

```
// Use a DbDataAdapter to return data from a SP using a DataTable
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
DbConnection connection = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);

var table = new DataTable();
DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("GetCountries", sqlConnection);
ProfiledDbDataAdapter prdataAdapter = new ProfiledDbDataAdapter(dataAdapter, null);

// null reference exception here - SelectCommand is null
prdataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

prdataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@countryID", 2));
prdataAdapter.Fill(table);

ViewBag.table = table;
```

Problem:  Null reference exception on SelectCommand

Please ignore lack of usings / disposing

I can successfully profile using ProfiledDbCommand to a SP:

```
// call a SP from DbCommand
var sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
DbConnection connection2 = new StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection2, MiniProfiler.Current);

if (connection2 != null)
{
    using (connection2)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the command.
            DbCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            ProfiledDbCommand prcommand = new ProfiledDbCommand(command, connection2, null);
            prcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            prcommand.CommandText = "dbo.GetCountries";
            prcommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@countryID", 3));
            prcommand.Connection = connection2;

            //command.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Countries";
            //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // Open the connection.
            connection2.Open();

            // Retrieve the data.
            DbDataReader reader = prcommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var text = reader["Name"];
                result += text + ", ";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Edit1:
This works:

```
// 2) SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter.. dataAdapter command - works
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
var table = new DataTable();
//var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("GetCountries", sqlConnection);
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from countries", sqlConnection);
//dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryID", 2);
dataAdapter.Fill(table);
```

This doesn't DataTable.. but does with DataSet

```
var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
DbConnection connection = new ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);

DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from countries", sqlConnection);
ProfiledDbDataAdapter prdataAdapter = new ProfiledDbDataAdapter(dataAdapter, null);

var table = new DataTable();
var dataset = new DataSet();

// Doesn't work
//prdataAdapter.Fill(table);
// Does work
prdataAdapter.Fill(dataset);
```

Comment: Does it only happen when going with a sproc to `DataTable` via `SqlDataAdapter`? Or does it also happen when you try to run plain sql through `SqlDataAdapter`?

Comment: It didn't work using plain SQL - same error.  I found it did work when using DataSet instead of DataTable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824852/how-to-hook-up-sqldataadapter-to-profile-db-operations-with-mvc-mini-profiler

Comment: Added code in the main question to update findings

Comment: Ok, based on what you are reporting, everything is pointing to a bug in the way that ProfiledDbConnection handles DataAdapter > DataTable operations. I will try to look into it when I can, but it will require building out a solution to replicate it (which takes more time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that though `ProfiledDbDataAdapter` inherited from `DbDataAdapter`, it did not override the default functionality of `DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`, leading to the errors that you saw.

I [fixed this](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/pull/41) in the MiniProfiler code. Fix is available in nuget, [version 3.0.10-beta7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/3.0.10-beta7) and higher.

I have tested this with your code from above and it works for me:

```
DbConnection connection = 
             new ProfiledDbConnection(sqlConnection, MiniProfiler.Current);    
var sql = "select * from countries";
DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConnection);
ProfiledDbDataAdapter prdataAdapter = new ProfiledDbDataAdapter(dataAdapter);    
var table = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(table);            // this now works
```

Comment: What about db parameters?

Comment: Since you fixed it, shouldn't the last line now had been prdataAdapter.Fill(table)?